# Usage of "not that bad a..."

Tags: sentence-construction, phrase-usage

Which of these is the correct usage? "She is not that bad a singer" or "She is not that bad of a singer."?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to the ELL. One line questions are discouraged on this site. See [tour](https://ell.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 1):

The standard, formal usage is 'She is not that bad a singer'. Dialectical 'of a' usages - mainly North American - *not that bad of a singer, not that big of a problem, not that hard of a job*, etc, are non-standard and should not be used in edited writing that attempts to be standard English.

[Not That Big of a Deal (Grammarphobia)](https://www.grammarphobia.com/blog/2014/01/not-that-big-of-a-deal.html)